# Microsoft excel formula on rounding up values

Tags: excel

If a value is less than 200, then it should be round up to 200. I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a stackoverflow question. You should try superuser.com instead.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit desperate. But thanks for the site reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use an if statement formula

```
=if(A1 < 200, 200, A1)
```

If cell A1 is less than 200, then it returns 200, otherwise it returns the value of A1.

Comment: Yep, this is right then. And it would be nice to accept this answer, mate...

Comment: This comment was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is called ceiling, and the function is `CEILING()`

In your case `CEILING(mynumber, 200)`. This will round any positive number less than or equal to 200 to 200. It will round 201 to 400, 401 to 600, an so on in multiples of 200.

In case you need to ceil only the numbers below 200, then `IF(mynumber < 200, 200, mynumber)`.

Comment: Ceiling will only work if you want to deal in multiples. 201 would round out to 400 for example. The question isn't very clear on that.

Comment: Can you help me arrive at a formula using CEILING? If a product is 200, say 1-199, id like a formula where it can be just rounded up to 200. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, agreed, Nick, I understood it in a way that he needs multiples of 200...

Comment: I mean if it's more than 200,  it should remain as is..

Comment: @user1953920 I have added an answer which should help you in that case.